# Inertia partial reload is updating parent

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I got this parent component, which has a tab bar that should load different components and lazy load the content:

```
<script setup>
import {Head} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";
import Card from "@/Components/Card.vue";
import {shallowRef} from "vue";
import Overview from "@/Pages/Unit/Tabs/Overview.vue";
import Offer from "@/Pages/Unit/Tabs/Offer/Index.vue";

defineProps({
    unit: {
        type: Object,
    },
    offers: {
        type: Array,
    },
})

const tabs = [
    {
        name: 'Overview',
        component: Overview
    },
    {
        name: 'Offers',
        component: Offer,
    },
]
const activeTab = shallowRef(tabs[0])
</script>

<template>

    <Head title="Unit"/>

    <AuthenticatedLayout>
        <Card class="mt-4 container" style="padding-bottom: 0;">
            <div role="tablist" class="tabs mt-2">
                <a v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.name" role="tab" class="tab"
                      :class="{'tab-active': activeTab.name === tab.name}" @click="activeTab = tab">{{ tab.name }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </Card>

        <div class="mt-4">
            <component :is="activeTab.component" :unit="unit"/>
        </div>

    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
</style>
```

And this is the `Index.vue`:

```
<script setup>
import Card from "@/Components/Card.vue";
import {router} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import {onMounted} from "vue";

const getOffers = () => {
    router.visit(route('unit.show', {unit: 1}), {
        only: ['offers']
    })
}

onMounted(() => {
    getOffers()
})
</script>

<template>
    <Card class="container">
            ...
    </Card>
</template>
```

and the controller method:

```php
public function show(Unit $unit): Response
{
    return inertia('Unit/Show', [
        'unit' => $unit
        'offers' => Inertia::lazy(fn () => $unit->offers),
    ]);
}
```

When I switch ma tab to the offer Tab, it imnediatly switches back to the overview tab. Why? I understand the partial reload using the only key in the visit method's options would prevent this side effect?